# Query result in a single row or multiple values in single with comma separated

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, pivot, transpose

I have three tables (stores, sales and products) with the following structure:

```
--Stores
IdStore   StoreName
1A        Store A
2B        Store B
3C        Store C

-- Products
IdProduct   Desc
1G          Product 1
2A          Product 2
3A          Product 3
4A          Product 4

--Sales
TicketNo  Store     Product     Qty
1001      Store A   Product 1   10
1002      Store A   Product 1   10
1003      Store B   Product 3   50
1004      Store A   Product 2   20
1005      Store A   Product 3   5
1006      Store B   Product 1   30
```

At the moment I have the following query:

```
SELECT S.StoreName, sum(SA.Qty), P.Desc
FROM SALES SA
cross apply (select top 1 * from Stores S where SA.Store = S.StoreName) S
cross apply (select top 1 * from Products P where SA.Product = P.Desc) P
group by S.StoreName, P.Desc
```

According to above table structure and data the query result is the following:

```
-- output
StoreName    Qty   Desc
Store A      20    Product 1
Store A      20    Product 2
Store A      5     Product 3
Store B      30    Product 1
Store B      20    Product 2
```

My question is if exists a way to get the same results but in different order and if is possible to get all the results from one store in one single row, something like this:

```
Store    Product 1  Product 2  Product 3
Store A  20         20         5    
Store B  30         20         0
```

Or something like:

```
Store     Result (in same line)
Store A   20;20;5;
Store B   30;20;0;
```

Comment: Those are two different things. What do you want and who is going to use the results? The second result can only be used for display for example

Comment: BTW you should be using a join, not CROSS APPLY and TOP 1

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?  That will determine which features are available.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I need to display this information to my users in a web app, but it's a lot of info a I want to make it in the best way possible, the ; result it's to handled it at front-end and the result also could be like this storename;20;20;5; etc...

Comment: @Brian I already add the tag. It's MSSQL 2012

Comment: @User1899289003 it would be a *lot* easier to do so on the client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should be using `INNER JOIN` not CROSS APPLY :

```
SELECT S.StoreName, P.Desc,sum(SA.Qty) as QTY
FROM SALES SA
    INNER JOIN Stores S ON SA.Store = S.StoreName
    INNER JOIN Products P ON SA.Product = P.Desc
group by S.StoreName, P.Desc
```

If the number of columns is known in advance you can convert rows to columns with the PIVOT operator :

```
SELECT S.StoreName, [Product 1], [Product 2], [Product 3]
FROM 
( SELECT SA.StoreName, P.Desc,SA.Qty
  FROM SALES SA
    INNER JOIN Stores S ON SA.Store = S.StoreName
    INNER JOIN Products P ON SA.Product = P.Desc
) Q
PIVOT 
(
    SUM(Qty)
    FOR Q.Desc IN ([Product 1], [Product 2], [Product 3])
) AS pvt
ORDER BY StoreName
```

Frankly though, it would probably be easier to generate the appropriate table on the client. PIVOT can't handle arbitrary numbers of columns. In ASP.NET on the other hand, one could use eg LINQ to group the data by store and product and then generate table rows based on that. If an ORM like Entity Framework is used, the data will be in the proper structure already.

Generating the required table could use two loops, eg :

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Store Name</th>
        <th>Product 1</th>
        ...
    </tr>
</thead>
@foreach(var store in Model.Stores)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@store.StoreName</td>
        @foreach(var product in store.Products.OrderBy(p=>p.Desc))
        {
           <td>@product.Qty</td>
        }
    </tr>
}
```

You could get all product names with LINQ, eg with :

```
var productNames = Stores.SelectMany(store=>store.Products)
                         .Select(p=>p.Desc)
                         .Distinct()
                         .OrderBy(desc=>desc)
                         .ToArray();
```

And use them to generate the headers themselves in a loop

Comment: Thank you very much! Using PIVOT option gives me the expected result!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. You will need the `PIVOT` function, but you need to defined the names of the products.

See a mockup below:

```
DECLARE @Stores TABLE(IdStore VARCHAR(100),[StoreName] VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @Stores 
--Stores
select '1A','Store A' UNION ALL
select '2B','Store B' UNION ALL
select '3C','Store C'


DECLARE @Products TABLE(IdProduct VARCHAR(100),[Desc] VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @Products 
-- Products
select '1G','Product 1' UNION ALL
select '2A','Product 2' UNION ALL
select '3A','Product 3' UNION ALL
select '4A',' Product 4'

DECLARE @Sales TABLE(TicketNo INT, Store  VARCHAR(100),[Product] VARCHAR(100), Qty INT);
INSERT INTO @Sales
--Sales
select '1001','Store A','Product 1','10' UNION ALL
select '1002','Store A','Product 1','10' UNION ALL
select '1003','Store B','Product 3','50' UNION ALL
select '1004','Store A','Product 2','20' UNION ALL
select '1005','Store A','Product 3','5' UNION ALL
select '1006','Store B','Product 1','30'




SELECT p.*
FROM 
(
    SELECT S.StoreName, SA.Qty, P.[Desc]
    FROM
        @SALES SA
    left join @Stores S on SA.Store = S.StoreName
    left join  @Products P on SA.Product = P.[Desc] 

)t
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Qty) FOR [Desc] IN ([Product 1],[Product 2],[Product 3] /*add as many as you need*/)
)p;
```